# How can I capture an event every time user disables/enables the location on the device?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

I have developed an ionic app which follows the Uber model. I am trying to capture the event when the user tries to disable the location between operations in the app. As soon as the user disables the location, he must be alarmed/requested about the location to continue.

I have already tried the diagnostic plugin in Cordova to capture the location on/off event.

```js
constructor(private diagnostic: Diagnostic) {
    let successCallback = (isAvailable:any) => { console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable); };

    let errorCallback = (e:any) => console.error(e);  

    this.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled().then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
}
```

**Expected Results**: Every time user disables location while using the app, he must get the location alert.

**Actual Results**: The user gets only an alert when the app is launched(killed and reopened). Not when the app is being used.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Its there in the description. The constructor is in app.component.ts

Comment: You could propably use [`watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition), which returns an updated position for the user. If it's disabled, an error would probably pop.

Comment: Its not about the position. I know watch position keeps a track of the location. If the location in device is off, then it should ask for the permission and not proceed further.

Comment: I think there is no events available to capture while user disabling the location. I'm not sure. Better you can use inside "set Interval" function you can write isGpsLocationEnabled() function  to check whether location is enabled or not for every particular seconds.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy Use this plugin inside your `watchPosition()` if watchPosition throws error use this plugin to Open Location.

Comment: No thats not required. I found the solution.

Comment: @Shankar_programmer Change handler did the trick for me.

Comment: Good to see. You got it : )

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Might help others. I am new to stack overflow, please don't mind the editing :)

```
    let successCallback = (isAvailable : any)=>{
        if(isAvailable === 'location_off')
 this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(()=>{console.log('requesting location')});

this.diagnostic.registerLocationStateChangeHandler(successCallback);
```